# arara allow bibtex to fail

Tags: bibtex, arara

Is there any way to tell arara, that it is ok, if bibtex fails?
I have to use a bibstyle provided for a document class, which produces an error for each entry. Now I still want to use arara, could I tell it to also accept a non-zero exit code for a given command? (Exit code is `2` in this case.)

Comment: Hello! Sadly, not with version 3.0 (the current version). In this particular build, a command is successful if and only if the exit code is `0`. In version 4.0 (waiting for a manual to be written), I included a custom way to set up which conditions have to be met for a command execution to be successful. So, to answer your question, this is not directly possible for now. Quick Q: which OS do you use? Maybe we can come up with a dirty trick to make things work, at least while I am trapped inside a thesis and have no time to write the manual for version 4.0 in a near future. `:)`

Comment: I'm using Linux so executing `bibtex || true` should work, but don't know, how to tell this to arara.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines. `:)` Give me a couple of minutes, I will test something and report back. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda beat you to it :D

Comment: @white_gecko in the unlikely event that you want to use `bibtex` command-line options, or in the likely even that you want a cleaner solution, you can use @PauloCereda 's [solution given in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37299183#37299183)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux you can write a script that returns 0 even if the BibTeX run was non-zero. In arara you can call this scipt instead of the normal bibtex rule.

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtexignore
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test with non-existing bibliography file

\cite{na}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{nonexisting}
\end{document}
```

`bibtexignore.yaml` (note that this is arara 3.0 syntax, see the [arara 4.0 manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-manual.pdf) for details on the new syntax using `commands` instead of `command`):

```
!config
identifier: bibtexignore
name: BibTeX (ignoring errors)
command: ./bibtexignore.sh @{file}
arguments: []
```

`bibtexignore.sh`:

```
bibtex $(basename $1 .tex)
true
```

`araraconfig.yaml` (in `/home/user`):

```
!config
paths:
- /home/user/path/to/yaml/file
```

Result:

```
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running BibTeX (ignoring errors)... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
```

Run arara with `-v` to see the actual `bibtex` errors.