# How to make arara work with bibtexu?

Tags: arara

I need to submit an article, so I have to follow journal's rules of using PdfLaTeX and BibTeX. And one of the records in bibliography is in Russian, so the only option for me is using `bibtexu`. If I run this chain one by one: `pdflatex -> bibtexu -> pdflatex -> pdflatex` all goes OK and I get a proper PDF file.

If now I add

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtexu
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

at the beginning of `tex` file and then run `arara file.tex` I get `<BibTeXu> ... FAILURE`. Using TeXLive 2019 with latest updates as of today on Windows 7. If I remove that Russian record and change `% arara: bibtexu` to `% arara: bibtex` everything works just fine. Well, I can run commands by hand in this particular case, but is it possible to use nice automatization machinery of `arara` with `bibtexu`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I probably have solution. I searched the forum and found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369038/arara-allow-bibtex-to-fail) discussion about how to ignore errors in commands during `arara` run. Actually, there are no real errors in the `bibtexu` run, it just issues warnings (I suppose this is because of the `bst` file I use) after each name and after each block:

```
This is BibTeXu: a UTF-8 Big BibTeX version 0.99d
Implementation:  Microsoft(R) C/C++ for Win32
Release version: 3.71 (04 mar 2019)
Compiled with:   ICU version 63.1

The top-level auxiliary file: file.aux
The style file: style.bst
Reallocated glb_str_ptr (elt_size=4) to 10 items from 0.
Reallocated global_strs (elt_size=20001) to 10 items from 0.
Reallocated glb_str_end (elt_size=4) to 10 items from 0.
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000.
Database file #1: file.bib
Warning--Gardner S.
Warning--Haxton W.C.
Warning--Holstein B.R.
Warning--after block
Warning--Kistryn S.
Warning--Lang J.
Warning--Liechti J.
Warning--Maier T.
Warning--Muller R.
Warning--Nessi-Tedaldi F.
Warning--Simonius M.
Warning--Smyrski J.
Warning--Jaccard S.
Warning--Haeberli W.
Warning--Sromicki J.
Warning--after block
Warning--Нурушев С.Б.
Warning--Рунцо М.Ф.
Warning--Стриханов М.Н.
Warning--after block
...

Here's how much of BibTeX's memory you used:
 Cites:                10 out of 750
 Fields:              344 out of 5000
 Hash table:        99608 out of 100000
 Strings:            1200 out of 100000
 Free string pool:  12934 out of 65000
 Wizard functions:   4014 out of 6000
(There were 100 warnings)
```

So, no errors, `bbl` file is correct, but the exit code of `bibtexu` for some reasons is not zero. I followed advices of referenced topic and added `exit: value > 0` to `bibtexu.yaml`:

```
!config
# Arara, the cool TeX automation tool
# Copyright (c) 2018, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda 
# All rights reserved.
#
# This rule is part of arara.
identifier: bibtexu
name: BibTeXu
authors:
- Marco Daniel
- Paulo Cereda
commands:
- name: An 8-bit implementation of BibTeX 0.99 with a very large capacity
  command: >
    @{
        return getCommand('bibtexu', options, getBasename(file));
    }
  exit: value > 0
arguments:
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

Well, maybe this is not true solution and only a dirty hack, but it works for me. Of course I have to check if the resulting bibliography is correct, all cites are correct, and they are!